# Question about function $f(x)=x\ln x-\frac{x^2}e+ax$, where $a$ is a parameter.

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to solve a hard question about function and here is the question below:

> For the given function $f(x)=x\ln x-\frac{x^2}e+ax$ (where $a$ is a parameter), we have such property:
> $$\exists\;x_1,x_2\,(x_1\not=x_2)\quad s.t.\quad f(x_1)=f(x_2)\quad f'(x_1)=f'(x_2)$$
> In this case, prove the inequality
> $$(a+1)^2x_1x_2-\sqrt{x_1x_2}\lt\frac34$$

To work this one out, I have tried a few things and finally got this
$$x_1x_2=\frac1{e^{2a}}\lt\frac{e^2}4$$
Can anyone help me continue this? (I'll put my work below.)

---

### My work of proving $x_1x_2=\frac1{e^{2a}}\lt\frac{e^2}4$

First, I calculate the derivative.
$$f'(x)=\ln x-\frac{2x}e+a+1$$
Because of the property of $f(x)$, we have the following equations:
$$\begin{cases}
f(x_1)=f(x_2)\Rightarrow x_1\ln x_1-\frac{{x_1}^2}e+ax_1=x_2\ln x_2-\frac{{x_2}^2}e+ax_2\\
f'(x_1)=f'(x_2)\Rightarrow\ln x_1-\frac{2x_1}e=\ln x_2-\frac{2x_2}e
\end{cases}$$
Simplify the second equation, we get
$$x_1-x_2=\frac e2(\ln x_1-\ln x_2)\tag{*}\label{*}$$
Simplify the first one, we have
$$x_1\ln x_1-x_2\ln x_2=\frac1e(x_1^2-x_2^2)-a(x_1-x_2)$$
$$\Rightarrow x_1\ln x_1-x_2\ln x_2=\frac1e(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2)-a(x_1-x_2)$$
$$\Rightarrow x_1\ln x_1-x_2\ln x_2\stackrel{\eqref{*}}=\frac12(\ln x_1-\ln x_2)(x_1+x_2)-\frac{ae}2(\ln x_1-\ln x_2)$$
$$\Rightarrow ea(\ln x_1-\ln x_2)=-(x_1-x_2)(\ln x_1+\ln x_2)$$
$$\Rightarrow 2a(\ln x_1-\ln x_2)\stackrel{\eqref{*}}=-(\ln x_1-\ln x_2)(\ln x_1+\ln x_2)$$
$$\Rightarrow \ln x_1x_2=-2a$$
$$\Rightarrow x_1x_2=\frac1{e^{2a}}$$
Then, let's calculate a vague range of a.
$$f''(x)=\frac1x-\frac2e$$
So at $x=\frac e2$, $f'(x)$ has a maximum.
$$[f'(x)]_{max}=f'(\frac e2)=-\ln2+1+a$$
In order to satisfy the property of $f(x)$, it is obvious that there must be an interval where $f'(x)\gt0$. So we have
$$[f'(x)]_{max}=-\ln2+1+a\gt0$$
$$\Rightarrow a\gt\ln2-1$$
$$\Rightarrow x_1x_2=\frac1{e^{2a}}\lt\frac{e^2}4$$

Comment: If $a$ is not bounded from above, the inequality won't work. You need to find the upper bound for $a$.

Comment: Plug $x_1x_2=e^{-2a}$ into the inequality you want to prove, and use your lower bound on $a$ (@Vasili no upper bound needed): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28a%2B1%29%5E2e%5E%28-2a%29-e%5E%28-a%29+from+a%3D-1+to+6